# ADFS 2.0 with ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2008-r2, adfs2.0

I wanted to implement a small Proof of Concept for ADFS integration with MVC application. For this I created a virtual machine for Windows 2008 R2 and configured ADDS, ADCS and added my updated my server domain to one created one using ADDS.

After this I created certificate using ADCS.

Now, installed ADFS 2.0 using Microsoft download of ADFSSetup.exe RTW. 
With help of some I configured ADFS & added relying party trust from my MVC application SSL URI.

After this I tried to run the application however started facing 403.14 error page.

Following observations as outcome from entire configuration:

1. I tried to access "<>/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml" and I
   got a proper XML which is as per expected.
2. I saw couple of entries from server computer - IIS website as like "http://<>/adfs/services/trust" OR "https://<>/adfs/ls/" however couldn't get any response from server. even I tried to access same from server using localhost instead of server names, then also no luck.
3. Then to cross-verify I checked IIS's default website where I found adfs/ls however it was a like a website. Not sure correct or not. I couldn't find anything 'services/trust' under ADFS IIS application.
4. After that I installed ADFS from Server manager and saw one more virtual directory 'fs',added under adfs application. when I tried to access 'fs' using https I am able to access it easily and can see SOAP  service and page displayed with available web method.

I tried to find more on 'adfs/ls' and 'adfs/services/trust' however couldn't get much more information.

Please, if anyone came across this issue. Do let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue, this is how ADFS works. Next step you have to configure claims providers and relying parties from ADFS management console (from Admin tools). Relying party could be a sample claims aware MVC application. It should work

Answer (score 0):

The only URL's that ADFS "answers" to are the federation metadata endpoint and the IDPInitiated one.

adfs/ls expects either WS-Federation or SAML parameters after it. On its own it will throw an error.

Then follow [How To: Build Claims-Aware ASP.NET MVC Web Application Using WIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh291061(v=vs.110).aspx).

Why are you using Windows 2008 R2? (ADFS 2.0)? You should rather use Windows 2012 R2 (ADFS 3.0).